# Singularities of phase interfaces in closed surfaces

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, riemannian-geometry, geometric-measure-theory, geometric-analysis, minimal-surfaces

Let $(\Sigma,g)$ be a compact surface without boundary. Given $\epsilon > 0$, the *$\epsilon$-Allen-Cahn equation* is the semilinear elliptic PDE $\epsilon \Delta_g u - \epsilon^{-1} W'(u) = 0$, with unknown a function $u: \Sigma \to \mathbf{R}$. This is the Euler-Lagrange equation of the eponymous function $E_{\epsilon}(u) = \int_\Sigma \frac{\epsilon}{2} \lvert \nabla u \rvert^2 + \frac{1}{\epsilon} W(u) \, \mathrm{d} \mu_g$, where $\mu_g$ is the volume form on $\Sigma$. The function $W: \mathbf{R} \to \mathbf{R}$ is a non-negative double-well, with two minima at $\pm 1$, where it is zero, and a non-degenerate local maximum between them. For example $W(t) = 1/4(1-t^2)^2$ is often chosen, in which case the equation becomes $\epsilon \Delta_g u - \epsilon^{-1}(u^3 -u) = 0$.

The critical points of this functional $E_\epsilon$ (or, equivalently, the solutions of the Allen-Cahn equation) describe diffuse phase interfaces in two-phase liquids. Loosely speaking as $\epsilon \to 0$ these phase interfaces concentrate on a (singular) network of geodesics. Below I briefly describe this phenomenon; experts may skip to the questions.

Let $\epsilon_j \to 0$, and $(u_j \mid j \in \mathbf{N})$ be a sequence of solutions of the equation. As $j \to \infty$, $u_j \to \pm 1$ almost everywhere on $\Sigma$, but for all $t \in (0,1)$, the level sets $\{ -t < u_j < t \}$ converge to a *geodesic net* $V$ say on $\Sigma$. (To ensure that $V$ is non-trivial, the sequence must have their energies $E_{\epsilon_j}(u_j)$ uniformly bounded from below.) This was proved by [Hutchinson-Tonegawa](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/PL00013453) in the Euclidean case, and modified to Riemannian manifolds by [Mantoulidis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05946).

In the language of geometric measure theory, $V$ is a *stationary $1$-varifold* in $\Sigma$. Geometrically, $V$ consists of a finite collection of vertices $\{ p_1,\dots,p_N \}$ connected by geodesic edges $\{ \gamma_1, \dots,\gamma_M \}$. These edges have positive integer multiplicities $\{ \theta_1, \dots, \theta_M \}$, and satisfy a *balancing condition* at every vertex. Let $p_i$ be a vertex of $V$, and $e_{ij} \in T_{p_i} \Sigma$ be the outward-pointing tangent vectors to all edges touching $p_i$. Then $\sum_j \theta_{ij} e_{ij} = 0$, where $\theta_{ij}$ are the multiplicities of the corresponding edges.

**Question 1**. What is known about the geodesic nets that can appear in the limit? Are there examples which are 'not immersed' in the sense that they are not unions of closed geodesics?

1. [Mantoulidis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1706.05946) proves that if the $u_j$ all have Morse index at most one, then $V$ in fact consists of a smoothly immersed geodesic, with at most one self-intersection. He moreover remarks that an argument due to him and Otis Chodosh gives bounds on the number of singularities (meaning vertices) of $V$ when the $u_j$ have uniformly bounded Morse indices; see Remark 1.6 on p. 4.
2. [Del Rio Guerra, Garza-Hume and Padilla](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02921880) have some results for surfaces whose curvature has a sign, showing that the limit is a closed geodesic. However these seem to apply only for critical points minimising the Allen-Cahn functional, subject to some constraint. Without index bounds one can construct examples on the round sphere $\mathbf{S}^2$ which converge to a union of equatorial geodesics.

**Question 2**. What is known about the case where $\Sigma = \mathbf{S}^2$ and $g$ has positive Gauss curvature? What singularities can appear when $\epsilon \to 0$ in this case?

For both questions I would be interested in results for sequences with bounded Morse indices, as well as for arbitrary sequences.

Comment: I am much more at home with minimizers. There your varifold has a natural orientation and if you treat it as a current is of multiplicity 1, which along bounded sequences should indeed exclude anything except single closed geodesics. But in your case I would focus on the local problem and do a blow-up around a single vertex. If you can construct a solution on the flat disk with a vertex at zero that is not an intersection of straight lines, then you can likely use there as building blocks on the sphere. If there is no such solution this likely leads to a proof for general surfaces.

Comment: It is an open question whether or not the limits of a sequence of bounded energy + bounded Morse index solutions to Allen--Cahn on a surface produces an immersed geodesic (even on the exact round $S^2$ or a perturbation of it). The analogous question for Almgren--Pitts min-max is also open; I believe that showing that Almgren--Pitts always produced immersed geodesics would imply the corresponding statement for Allen--Cahn by https://arxiv.org/abs/2004.05120.

Comment: If you dont assume bounded Morse index (just bounded energy), it's also unknown if there are more exotic solutions. I would guess that this doesn't gain you much freedom actually, but I am not sure.

Comment: @OtisChodosh Thank you for your helpful; I have two follow-up questions. You do not mention this explicitly, but is it correct to infer for example that the solutions of the Allen-Cahn equation on the round $\mathbf{S}^2$ that vanish on the union of two orthogonal equators have finite index? I am bit confused because this is false in higher dimensions, so there would be unstable deformations there which cannot decrease the energy in $\mathbf{S}^2$. Second, is it known (or suspected) that every finite index solution of the Allen-Cahn equation can be obtained via min-max arguments? [...]

Comment: [...] Were this to fail, then a positive answer to the question for the geodesic nets obtained via the Almgren-Pitts construction---that they are necessarily immersed---might fail to capture some nets obtained in the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$ from bounded-index solutions of the Allen-Cahn equation, no? (Specifically it might not account for those exotic solutions that cannot be obtained via min-max.)

Comment: Those solutions probably have index 2, although I dont think anyone has ever proven this exact statement. The point is that like in Mantoulidis's work a "crossing" (at the level of the geodesic net) corresponds to some concentration of index. (You can look up the saddle solution to Allen--Cahn on $\mathbb{R}^2$ which has index 1).[...]

Comment: You have to make precise what you mean by "min-max methods", but I would expect that on the exact sphere this is unknown (basically, it is not clear if the Allen--Cahn functional is Morse-Bott) but after perturbing the metric the AC functional is Morse. You can email me if you have more questions.